# How to total unique column value by hourly date time range?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query I have been working on and can't piece together the last portion. I would like the below query to return a total count per hour, based on the StartTime range given, for the column [Meta_ID] and have the total only count [Meta_ID] uniquely for that hour with no dupes. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```
 SELECT [Detail_ID]
,[Meta_ID] as PlayerID
,p.FirstName
,p.LastName
,u.FirstName as Host
,[StartTime]
,CAST(StartTime as date) AS ForDate,
       DATEPART(hour,StartTime) AS OnHour,
       COUNT(*) AS Totals
FROM [SDIDW].[dbo].[CDS_StatDetail] (nolock)
join CDS_Player p on p.Player_ID = Meta_ID
join CDS_User u on u.User_ID = p.HostUser_ID
--join dbo.PlayerDAP d on d.PlayerId = Meta_ID
WHERE StartTime >= '2017-06-04 00:00:00.000'
AND StartTime <= '2017-06-10 23:59:59.999'
AND StatType like '%SLOT%'
AND Meta_ID in (
10,
111,
112,
126,
127,
147,
155,
189,
234,
237,
271,
273,
287,
321,
404)
GROUP BY CAST(StartTime as date),
       DATEPART(hour,StartTime),
 [Detail_ID]
,[Meta_ID]
,p.FirstName
,p.LastName
,u.FirstName
,[StartTime]
```

This is currently what I am getting. I have removed the names in this table.

```
+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------+--------+--------+
| Detail_ID | PlayerID |    StartTime    | ForDate  | OnHour | Totals |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------+--------+--------+
| 209381040 |     1115 | 6/4/17 12:08 AM | 6/4/2017 |      0 |      1 |
| 209381317 |     1115 | 6/4/17 12:15 AM | 6/4/2017 |      0 |      1 |
| 209381453 |      492 | 6/4/17 12:10 AM | 6/4/2017 |      0 |      1 |
| 209381800 |     1891 | 6/4/17 12:36 AM | 6/4/2017 |      0 |      1 |
| 209381805 |     1200 | 6/4/17 12:37 AM | 6/4/2017 |      0 |      1 |
| 209382181 |     1200 | 6/4/17 12:48 AM | 6/4/2017 |      0 |      1 |
| 209382753 |     1069 | 6/4/17 12:13 AM | 6/4/2017 |      0 |      1 |
| 209382581 |     1200 | 6/4/17 1:02 AM  | 6/4/2017 |      1 |      1 |
| 209383570 |     1069 | 6/4/17 1:10 AM  | 6/4/2017 |      1 |      1 |
| 209383752 |     1069 | 6/4/17 1:47 AM  | 6/4/2017 |      1 |      1 |
| 209386313 |      126 | 6/4/17 5:10 AM  | 6/4/2017 |      5 |      1 |
| 209386352 |      126 | 6/4/17 5:22 AM  | 6/4/2017 |      5 |      1 |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------+--------+--------+
```

But what I am wanting to get is more along the lines of the added columns on the right as seen below. I'm trying to get a unique count of Meta_ID per hour.

```
+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------+--------+--------+------+--------+
| Detail_ID | PlayerID |    StartTime    | ForDate  | OnHour | Totals | Hour | Hosted |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------+--------+--------+------+--------+
| 209381040 |     1115 | 6/4/17 12:08 AM | 6/4/2017 |      0 |      1 |    0 |      5 |
| 209381317 |     1115 | 6/4/17 12:15 AM | 6/4/2017 |      0 |      1 |    1 |      2 |
| 209381453 |      492 | 6/4/17 12:10 AM | 6/4/2017 |      0 |      1 |    5 |      1 |
| 209381800 |     1891 | 6/4/17 12:36 AM | 6/4/2017 |      0 |      1 |      |        |
| 209381805 |     1200 | 6/4/17 12:37 AM | 6/4/2017 |      0 |      1 |      |        |
| 209382181 |     1200 | 6/4/17 12:48 AM | 6/4/2017 |      0 |      1 |      |        |
| 209382753 |     1069 | 6/4/17 12:13 AM | 6/4/2017 |      0 |      1 |      |        |
| 209382581 |     1200 | 6/4/17 1:02 AM  | 6/4/2017 |      1 |      1 |      |        |
| 209383570 |     1069 | 6/4/17 1:10 AM  | 6/4/2017 |      1 |      1 |      |        |
| 209383752 |     1069 | 6/4/17 1:47 AM  | 6/4/2017 |      1 |      1 |      |        |
| 209386313 |      126 | 6/4/17 5:10 AM  | 6/4/2017 |      5 |      1 |      |        |
| 209386352 |      126 | 6/4/17 5:22 AM  | 6/4/2017 |      5 |      1 |      |        |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------+--------+--------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Sample data (as DDL + DML) and desired result would improve your chances of getting an accurate answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have added some more detail. Thanks for the suggestion. New to this so still learning. Took me a while to figure out how to format the tables lol.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT [Detail_ID]
,[Meta_ID] as PlayerID
,p.FirstName
,p.LastName
,u.FirstName as Host
,[StartTime]
FROM [SDIDW].[dbo].[CDS_StatDetail] (nolock)
join CDS_Player p on p.Player_ID = Meta_ID
join CDS_User u on u.User_ID = p.HostUser_ID
--join dbo.PlayerDAP d on d.PlayerId = Meta_ID
WHERE convert(varchar(8),StartTime,106) >= convert(varchar(8) ,'2017-06-04 00:00:00.000',106)
AND     WHERE convert(varchar(8),StartTime,106) <=     WHERE convert(varchar(8),'2017-06-10 23:59:59.999',106)
AND StatType like '%SLOT%'
AND Meta_ID in (
10,
111,
112,
126,
127,
147,
155,
189,
234,
237,
271,
273,
287,
321,
404)a
```

Comment: WHERE convert(varchar(8),yourdatetimevalue,106) return time as HH:mm:ss